# Calculating Ekman transport and vertical velocity from wind stress τ of mesoscale cyclone

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm working through problems in the Vallis 'big book' and I'm stuck on the following problem:

Consider a wind stress imposed by a mesoscale cyclonic storm (in the atmosphere) given by

τ = −Aexp{−(r/λ)^2} (yi −xj)

where r2 = x2 + y2, and A and λ are constants. Also assume constant Coriolis gradient β = ∂f/∂y and constant ocean depth H. In the ocean, find (a) the Ekman transport, (b) the vertical velocity wE(x, y, z)below the Ekman layer, (c) the northward velocity v(x, y, z)below the Ekman layer and (d) indicate how you would find the westward velocity u(x, y, z)below the Ekman layer.

I have separated the equation into the x and y components. The transport in the U and V directions should be τ(y)/pf and -τ(x)/pf, respectively (though does this assume a f-plane?). But the vertical velocity gets very messy, and I can't seem to simplify it.